# Why are my requests from urllib2 delayed with Apache2?

Tags: python, apache, iis, urllib2

I'm dealing with two internal web servers, one running Apache2 on Ubuntu Server 10.04, and the other IIS on Windows Server 2008.  When I hit either of the root URLs from a web browser with a cleared cache, calling the server by IP address, both pop up with no delay.  I also see no delays browsing sites on either server.  However, when I call the same addresses using `urllib2` in Python, each request to the Apache2 server is delayed by 4.5 to 5 seconds.  The IIS server responds in less than 0.02.

Here is a script I ran to verify the problem.  I set the User-Agent in case it makes a difference, but it doesn't appear to:

```
import urllib2
from time import time

apache_server = 'http://192.168.1.101/'
iis_server = 'http://192.168.1.102/'

headers = {'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i586; de; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0",}

print('Contacting Apache2 server...')
request = urllib2.Request(url=apache_server, headers=headers)
start = time()
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
elapsed = time() - start
print('Elapsed time: {0}'.format(elapsed))

print('Contacting IIS server...')
request = urllib2.Request(url=iis_server, headers=headers)
start = time()
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
elapsed = time() - start
print('Elapsed time: {0}'.format(elapsed))
```

Results:

```
>python urltest.py
Contacting Apache2 server...
Elapsed time: 4.55500006676

Contacting IIS server...
Elapsed time: 0.0159997940063
```

**What difference is there between a browser request and my `urllib2` request that would explain this delay?**

I've seen similar problems with SSH caused by reverse DNS lookup, but I have `HostnameLookups Off` in my Apache2 config.  I don't know if anything else could be triggering a lookup.

---

*Update:* I followed the exchange with Wireshark, and found three failed NBNS queries going from my machine to the Apache2 server before they finally start talking. This accounted for the lost time.  I tried adding an entry in `hosts` for the web server, which eliminated the delay.

I'm not adding this as an answer because I still don't know why the lookup attempt is happening, or why I don't see the same behavior from the web browser.  I just have a workaround for whatever mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup is happening because that's what Windows does. It's always going to check NetBIOS before anything else.

Further reading:

- [Microsoft TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172218)
- [NetBIOS over TCP/IP Name Resolution and WINS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/119493/EN-US)

Comment: I'm providing an IP address from the start, so there's no name to resolve.  Is there something special about my `urllib2` request that would trigger a reverse lookup, while a browser request goes straight through?